# how facebook design resolves the performance issue to fetch friend list?

Tags: database, performance, facebook

I have a web design issue regarding to performance to ask advice. On a web site, there are many personalized information, for example the friends of a user of facebook. Personalized I mean different users have different friend list.

Suppose friend list is stored in database like Oracle or Mysql, each time the user clicks Home of his/her facebook page or login, we need to read database again. Each time the user add/remove friend, the database needs some update operations.

My question is, I think the performance capability (e.g. concurrency of transactions of read/write) of database is limited, and if facebook is using database to store friend list, it is hard to implement the good performance. But if not using database (e.g. MySql or Oracle), how did Facebook implement such personalization function?

Comment: Sharding and delayed transactions (in this case, it doesn't matter if your friend list is slightly outdated when others are viewing it).

Comment: What means "Sharding and delayed transactions"? Could you give me a tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a pretty good article about the technology behind facebook.](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/facebook-work-nuts-bolts-technology-explained/)

As Justin said, it looks like a combination of Memcached and Cassandra.

Comment: Cassandra could only work on Linux? Any similar kinds of open source products which could work on Windows?

Comment: [Here is a solution](http://coderjournal.com/2010/03/cassandra-jump-start-for-the-windows-developer/) if you want to run it on a virtual linux install... it seems to be the only option for windows

Comment: Thanks Azkar, question answered.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook and other large sites typically use a caching layer to store that kind of data so that you don't have to make a round trip to the database each time you need to fetch it.

One of the most popular is [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) (which, last I remember reading, is used by Facebook).

You could also check out how some sites are using NoSQL databases as their caching layer. I actually just read an article yesterday about how StackOverflow utilizes [Redis](http://redis.io/) to handle their caching.

Comment: Another question is, I think memcached only improves performance if read many times for a single object? Correct?

Comment: @George2 - It supports adding data to the cache, but not writing it back to the database. Keep in mind that the bulk of the operations on Facebook still revolve around fetching data. I'm not sure how they handle persisting their data.

Comment: @George2 - That is correct. In your example, each users friends would be fetched a single time from the database and then retrieved from the cache for each subsequent page load. Depending on the expiration time on the cache, you might even re-use cached items across sessions for a given user.

Comment: why fetching data into memcached could improve performance? I think even if read database, only once for each user to get friend list. In order to fetch data into memcached, needs to read from database once as well. So, no save (both methods read database once). Any comments?

Comment: @George2 - One read per user isn't going to kill the performance of your application (as long as you have your hardware environment configured correctly for the application load).

Comment: You mean facebook frequently read the same information (use friend list)?

Comment: Why need to read multiple times if no update for friend list?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather they use a MySQL cluster and memcached and lots of custom written software. They open source plenty of it: http://developers.facebook.com/opensource/

Comment: I don't know. If you want to run a high performance website on multiple servers I would strongly advise against Windows.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to use a super-fast NoSQL-style database.  Start with [Simon Willison's excellent tutorial](http://simonwillison.net/static/2010/redis-tutorial/) on [redis](http://redis.io/), and it will all begin to become clear :)

Comment: Any kinds of NoSQL which could work on Windows? Redis could only work on Linux, correct?

Comment: well, it seems Windows binaries are available at https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads (haven't tried them), but, seriously, your concerned about Facebook-level performance and you're going to use Windows?

Comment: I have system based on both Windows and Linux, so looking for some cross-platform solutions.